# Minify and obfuscate multiple javascript files at once

Tags: javascript, obfuscation, minify

I want to minify and obfuscate multiple javascript files at once but keeping the way they are linked (name of variables and functions)

Do you know any software that could help ?

Comment: Can you combine them into one file and then obfuscate?

Comment: I believe most minifiers are smart enough not to rename global scope objects... not positive about that though. Looking forward to an answer to this too.

Comment: You can also convert multiple files into multiple obfuscated files instead of having one single obfuscated files. Check out my answer that I just posted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pick whatever suits you best.

1. [Closure Compiler](http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/) ([online sandbox](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home)).
2. [YUI Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/)
3. [UglifyJS](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS)

Answer (score 2):

You can also convert multiple js files into multiple obfuscated files instead of having one single obfuscated files.
I've created a solution and explained it on my blog. Please take a look:
http://adilsblogs.blogspot.com/2012/07/obfuscating-multiple-js-files-using-yui.html

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS

Answer (score 1):

Our [ECMAScript Obfuscator](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/Obfuscators/ECMAScriptObfuscator.html) does this.   It builds a map remember how it obfuscated names, and you can reobfuscate individual files, or new files, and extend the map, without breaking what has already been obfuscated.